# Why is this INNER JOIN/ORDER BY mysql query so slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, sql-order-by, limit

I have very big database of customers. This query was ok before I added `ORDER BY`. How can I optimize my query speed?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers 
LEFT JOIN ids ON customer_ids.customer_id = customers.customer_id AND ids.type = '10'
ORDER BY customers.name LIMIT 10";
```

`ids.type` and `customers.name` are my indexes

**Explain query**

```
id  select_type  table      type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra   
1   SIMPLE       customers  ALL     NULL            NULL    NULL        NULL    955     Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE       ids        ALL     type            NULL    NULL        NULL    3551    Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

Comment: If you can add good indexes to other fields, do so. This makes sense btw because with order by, it needs the entire results set first before it can rearrange it. Also, what are your primary keys?

Comment: Your query is syntactically incorrect.  `customer_ids` is not defined.

Comment: He is referring to the fact that customer_ids is used in his join criteria but is in fact not one of the tables that was joined on.  Can you show the results of an EXPLAIN on the above query?

Comment: @Isaiah: because the `from` clause does not contain such a table: `FROM customers LEFT JOIN ids ON ...` so the query contains a reference to the table `customers` and the  table `ids`.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote this query as a example and that's why there is wrong table name. It should be `LEFT JOIN ids ON ids.customer_id...`

Comment: My primary keys are rows id. Because is it true that primary key should be unique. I don't have any other unique fields.

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I assume you meant to type `ids.customer_id = customer.customer_id` and not customer_ids.customer_id)

Without the ORDER BY mysql grabbed the first 10 ids of type 10 (indexed), looked up the customer for them, and was done.  (Note that the LEFT JOIN here is really an INNER JOIN because the join conditions will only hold for rows that have a match in both tables)

With the ORDER BY mysql is probably retrieving *all* type=10 customers then sorting them by first name to find the first 10.

You could speed this up by either denormalizing the customers table (copy the type into the customer record) or creating a mapping table to hold the `customer_id, name, type` tuples.  In either case, add an index on `(type, name)`.  If using the mapping table, use it to do a 3-way join with customers and ids.

If type=10 is reasonably common, you could also force the query to walk the customers table by name and check the type for each with STRAIGHT JOIN.  It won't be as fast as a compound index, but it will be faster than pulling up all matches.

And as suggested above, run an EXPLAIN on your query to see the query plan that mysql is using.

Comment: What is a "STRAIGHT" join?

Comment: straight join is a mysql join type that walks the left table and joins the rows found with right table.  Unlike the other joins where the query optimizer chooses the order in which to read the tables, straight join lets the programmer specify.

Comment: I added EXPLAIN query records

Comment: STRAIGHT_JOIN has an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT is the problem.  By saying LEFT JOIN, you are implying that some `customers` may not have a corresponding row(s) in `ids`.  And you are willing to accept NULLs for the fields in place of such an `ids` row.

If that is not the case, then remove LEFT.  Then make sure you have an index on `ids` that *starts* with `type`.  Also, `customers` must have an index (probably the `PRIMARY KEY`) starting with `customer_id`.  With those, the optimizer can start with `ids`, filter on `type` earlier, thereby have less work to do.

But, still, it must collect lots of rows before doing the sort (`ORDER BY`); only then can it deliver the 10 (`LIMIT`).

While you are at it, add `INDEX(customer_id)` to `ids` -- that is what is killing performance for the LEFT version.